# How can I add a placeholder to a contenteditable div?

Tags: placeholder

How can I add a placeholder to a contenteditable div like allowed in a input or textarea field?

```
<textarea placeholder="Enter content here..."></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function checkNoLabel(divId,type) {

    if (type == "off") {
        if (document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML == "" || document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML == "<br>") {
            document.getElementById(divId).style.color = "silver";
            document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = "Enter content here...";
        }
    }
    if (type == "on") {
        if (document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML == "Enter content here...") {
            document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById(divId).style.color = "black";
        }
    }
}

</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="theDivId" style="color:silver" onFocus="checkNoContent(this.id,'on')" onBlur="checkNoContent(this.id,'off')">Enter content here...</div>
```

This will put a placeholder on blur (on click/tab away) if the field is empty and will remove the placeholder on focus (click/tab).